# Can Materials be transferred to the UV Map?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Good day,
I was wondering whether it was possible to apply any materials I've made to my Objects/Faces directly unto the UV Map.

I'm satisfied with how my Model looks with the materials, but to export it to a game it needs to have a UV Map only. I just never get the same results painting over the UV Map in Gimp.

Comment: UV map is just a coordinate system. You don't transfer anything to it. What you can do is to store all the materials information in textures that will be projected using the UVmap. This is called Baking, and there's plenty of info how to correctly do this in Blender.

Comment: you need to bake the materials to a texture. search for "texture baking"